# How to apply the same CSS class name, from different CSS resources, using C and GTK4

Tags: css, gtk4

Still can't understand how are working CSS classes in GTK(4).

I have 10 CSS files. All these files have the classes with the same names.
I need load these 10 CSS files at the same time, and apply style name to some GTK WIDGETs into window.

```
    css = gtk_css_provider_new(); // Create gtk css provider
    
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0.5); // Create example GTK widget. 
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(css, "file1.css"); // Load CSS from file1.css
    gtk_widget_add_css_class(box, "main_color"); // Adding style named main_color, to box
    
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0.5); // Create example GTK widget. 
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(css, "file2.css"); // Load CSS from file2.css
    gtk_widget_add_css_class(box, "main_color"); // Adding style named main_color, to box
    
    box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0.5); // Create example GTK widget.
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_path(css, "file3.css"); // Load CSS from file3.css
    gtk_widget_add_css_class(box, "main_color"); // Adding style named main_color, to box
```

The problem what I have - according to DOCS what I'm exploring, window might have only one CSS style - current. So after this block, all 10 widgets (boxes in my example) will have stylesheet from file10.css, as last file which was loaded.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The way Gtk handles css assumes that you will have a single css file and within it create different classes with different names for each situation. And if you want to change the origin of the css, you will change it for the entire application. This makes total sense.

I don't see in which situation it would make sense to have a class with the same name with different attributes in several css files instead of classes with different names in a single css file.